# Extract Argument from C Macro

Tags: c, macros, arguments, c-preprocessor

I have a number of definitions consisting of two comma-separated expressions, like this:

```
#define PIN_ALARM  GPIOC,14
```

I want to pass the second expression of those definitions (14 in the case above) to unary macros like the following:

```
#define _PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(n)          (1U << ((n) * 2U))
```

How can I extract the second number? I want a macro, call it "PICK_RIGHT", which will do this for me:

```
#define PICK_RIGHT(???)   ???
```

So that I can make a new macro that can take my "PIN" definitions:

```
#define PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(???) _PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(PICK_RIGHT(???))
```

And I can simply do:

```
#define RESULT   PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(PIN_ALARM)
```

Comment: Just use macros to do simple stuff. That is their function

Comment: I would consider not using macros in your case, but generating the C code (in some header or some included code file) with some script (e.g. in `awk` on POSIX). Or use an external preprocessor like [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)

Comment: By defining the port and the bit separately. Anyway, what is a "unary macro"?

Comment: Note that names beginning with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation to use; you should not create such names yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use macros for this. If you must, the following will work by throwing away the left part first so just the number remains. Use with care. No guarantees.

```
#define PIN_ALARM  GPIOC,14
#define RIGHTPART_ONLY(a,b) b

#define PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(a) RIGHTPART_ONLY(a)

#define RESULT   PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(PIN_ALARM)

int main (void)
{
    printf ("we'll pick ... %d\n", PIN_MODE_OUTPUT(PIN_ALARM));
    printf ("or maybe %d\n", RESULT);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want the left part as a string, you can use this (with the same warnings as above), where the left part gets converted to a string by `#`:

```
#define LEFTPART_ONLY(a,b) #a
#define PIN_MODE_NAME(a) LEFTPART_ONLY(a)
```

There is a *practical* reason this is not entirely without problems. `GPIOC` is a *symbol* and as such it is possibly defined elsewhere. Fortunately, it is not a problem if it is undefined, or it is but to a simple type - after all, first thing the macros do is "throw away the left part". But as Jonathan Leffler comments

> Note that if `GPIOC` maps to a macro containing commas, you're likely to get compilation errors.

Comment: +1 For some reason I just assumed this wouldn't work, without testing it, even though I knew the trick of passing through another macro to expand it in pre-processor (for `a##b` type pasting)... Given that it works, I'm not sure if the "no guarantees" caveat is even required - I'd say the more relevant caveat is code readability.

Comment: @Arkku: I had to try several iterations of nesting macros to get it to work (one of them used `atoi`..). Anyway, to me it feels too much like abusing C and its macros – they are not *designed* for this kind of manipulations.

Comment: Nice work.  Note that if GPIOC maps to a macro containing commas, you're likely to get compilation errors from this (try adding `#define GPIOC 19,13` to the code in the question, for example).  GCC complained about invoking a macro with 3 arguments instead of the expected 2 arguments, for example.

Comment: @Jongware: You are right to tell me not to use macros for this. I took the ugly approach of splitting each PIN_XXX definition out into separate port and pin definitions. The result is simpler, if more verbose.